# How long does Snow Spider (Frost) Paralysis last?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monsters, poison

The snow spider is a monster detailed on pages 154 and 155 of Frostburn (AKA It's Cold Outside) and has a poison listed as 1dx dex damage (based on spider size) and it has paralysis as a secondary damage, but it lists no duration. Errata also doesn't explain it, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## A *Dungeon* magazine adventure that uses snow spiders provides a duration even though *Frostburn* doesn't

In the adventure "Raiders of the Black Ice" (*Dungeon* #115 17–35) by [Wolfgang Baur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfgang_Baur)—one of *Frostburn*'s co-authors—, Medium snow spiders like those found in *Frostburn* (154–5) make an appearance. In that adventure, a snow spider's poison's secondary damage is listed as paralysis with a duration of 2d4 minutes.

Because a snow spider's poison's initial damage scales with its size, a DM may rule that its paralysis duration also scales—a Small snow spider's paralysis lasting 1d6 min. and a Large one's lasting 2d6 min.—as per Effect of Weapon Size (*Dungeon Master's Guide* 28).

---

***Note:*** A similar information gap is present in Frostburn *with the can-be-bought-for-gp poison snow spider blood (16) that has as its initial damage paralysis. The* Dungeon Master's Guide *on [Poison](http://dndsrd.net/abilitiesAndConditions.html#poison) (296) says that if a poison's initial damage is paralysis, that paralysis lasts 2d6 min. (Although that figure covers a poison listed in the accompanying table, the information is nonetheless presented in a general way.)*